# копирование xfs файловой системы не позволено

Tags: linux, centos

Есть centos 7. После последнего обновления, по моему перестало происходить копирование `xfs_copy /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`, Выдается ошибка `Error: source filesystem log is dirty. Mount the filesystem to replay the
log, unmount and retry xfs_copy`. Не доходит в чем дело. Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Вы забыли написать в вопросе, что получилось во время выполнения предложенной рекомендации.

Comment: она смонтрирована. Это рабочая корневая файловая система, на боевом сервере

Comment: Запланируйте время обслуживания, и сделайте как просят.